# IPTables rule to log then drop packets than contains a hex-string found via TCDUMP

Tags: iptables, tcpdump, netfilter

Using TCP Dump i captured this packet which is all the time making my software unavailable.

```
18:56:58.979504 IP Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal.13333 > XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.60323: Flags [.], ack 47, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 26672837 ecr 695829589], length 0
    0x0000:  f4cc 554b 552c 5404 a6a6 8f40 0800 4500  ..UKU,T....@..E.
    0x0010:  0034 0ac8 4000 4006 25aa b009 6f56 bca5  .4..@.@.%...oV..
    0x0020:  2e4d 2f4f eba3 ffa0 f75a aac5 8dfb 8010  .M/O.....Z......
    0x0030:  00e3 72ad 0000 0101 080a 0196 fec5 2979  ..r...........)y
    0x0040:  8455
```

After several inspections, i noticed that this packet has a fixed part which remain unchanged in every captured packet,this part is situated in the offset `0x0010` exactley : `b009 6f56 bca5`.
First of all i attempt to log this packet when arrived using iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 13333 -m string --algo bm --hex-string "|b0096f56bca5|" -j LOG --log-prefix "b009-6f56-bca5:"
```

Unfortunately this iptables rule don't work.But when i changed it to :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 13333 -m string --algo bm --hex-string "|bca5|" -j LOG --log-prefix "b009-6f56-bca5:"
```

It work without any issues.
What is wrong with the 1st rule? I already tried `"|b009 6f56 bca5|"` without success.

Any help will be appreciated.
Best regards.

Comment: What happens if you set the hex string to the hex in pairs eg b0 09 6f ..

Comment: even this rule not work! `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 13333 -m string --algo bm --hex-string "|b0 09 6f 56 bc a5|" -j LOG --log-prefix "b009-6f56-bca5: : "`

Comment: I maybe clutching at straws but what if you change the algo to kmp

Comment: `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 13333 -m string --algo kmp --hex-string "|b0 09 6f 56 bc a5|" -j LOG --log-prefix "b009-6f56-bca5: "` Same result.Not working

Comment: Very odd..  I have heard that sometimes strings dont match the first two packets, but, im all out of ideas.. Sorry

Comment: Me too i'm out of ideas, i spent a day to understand why the rule work for `bca5` but not for `b0096f56bca5`

Comment: Its clearly finding some reason not to match it, but its crappy it cant/wont explain why!

Comment: I checked all the packets have the same structure and size, only the above part remain the same.

Comment: I tried this iptables syntax in 'Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS',  it works fine. The content of ip packet you captured is weird to me, you did some modification considering privacy issue? Have you tried |6f56 bca5| or |b009 6f56| ?

Answer (score 0):

Not working tcpdump command:

```
tcpdump -XX src port 13333
```

bad output :

```
18:56:58.979504 IP Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal.13333 > XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.60323: Flags [.], ack 47, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 26672837 ecr 695829589], length 0
    0x0000:  f4cc 554b 552c 5404 a6a6 8f40 0800 4500  ..UKU,T....@..E.
    0x0010:  0034 0ac8 4000 4006 25aa b009 6f56 bca5  .4..@.@.%...oV..
    0x0020:  2e4d 2f4f eba3 ffa0 f75a aac5 8dfb 8010  .M/O.....Z......
    0x0030:  00e3 72ad 0000 0101 080a 0196 fec5 2979  ..r...........)y
    0x0040:  8455
```

Working tcpdump command :

```
tcpdump -nnSOX "src host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" and "dst port 13333"
```

good output :

```
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
05:49:49.631211 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.57625 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.13333: Flags [S],   seq 1036987151, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 770422252 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  4514 003c 9ee3 4000 3a06 9772 bca5 2e4d  E..<..@.:..r...M
    0x0010:  b009 6f56 e119 2f4f 3dcf 2b0f 0000 0000  ..oV../O=.+.....
    0x0020:  a002 7210 6e7e 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ..r.n~..........
    0x0030:  2deb b5ec 0000 0000 0103 0307            -...........
```

The rule that works for me :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 13333 -m string --algo bm --hex-string "|bca52e4db0096f56|" -j LOG --log-prefix "Bad Packet:"
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 13333 -m string --algo bm --hex-string "|bca52e4db0096f56|" -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for you to try

```
iptables -I INPUT -j DROP -p tcp --dport 13333 -m string --algo bm --hex-string "|bca52e4db0096f56|"
```